# Accessing a class defined in one ES6 file from another, using traceur

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, traceur

I'm trying to use ES6 syntax with the help of traceur-compiler.

Here's my index.html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
  traceur.options.experimental = true;
</script>

<script type="module" src="src/myclass.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/main.js"></script>
```

Here's my myclass.js

```
'use strict';
class MyClass {
}

var localmc = new MyClass(); // Works
```

Here's my main.js

```
'use strict';
window.onload = function () {
  var mc = new MyClass(); // Throws error, Why?
}
```

How do I make MyClass visible in main.js?

I also tried assigning `MyClass` to `window` object, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this

In main.js

```
'use strict';
window.onload = function () {
  System.import('src/myclass').then(function (myclass) {
    var mc = new myclass.MyClass(); // works
  });
}
```

I imagine, when a proper module system is implemented in browsers for ES6, this mechanism will have to be replaced. But this should do for now.